# How to convert a string to a key for hash table

Tags: c#, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

I need to convert a string (max. length = 20, consisting of random lower alphabetical characters and/or numbers) to a key for a hash table that holds slots for a max of 100.000 keys. What I tried is to convert each of the chars within the string to a number between 0 and 36 (since 36 posibilities for each char) and calculate the number for the string, counting as a positional numeral system with base 36:

```
long val = 0;
long v;
long pow = name.Length-1;
foreach (char c in name) {
    if (char.IsNumber(c))
        v = (long)c;
    else
        v = char.ToUpper(c) - 54; 
    val += v * (long)Math.Pow((double)36, (double)pow);
    Console.WriteLine(v+","+pow+","+val);
    pow--;
}
```

Then I tried using tolong(somestring) % 100000 to map the strings to keys between 0 and 9999. However the results of the tolong function amount to huge numbers which long can't even handle.

Could anyone help me out on how I could do this conversion right?

Comment: Why not use `name.GetHashCode()` ?

Comment: use `name.GetHashCode()%100000`

Comment: @Habib I did not know about that function, thank you, however I need to create my own working hashtable without using built-in hashtable related functions as an exercise to be honest, but I'm stuck at the conversion.

Comment: Have you tried [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? You could also just use [MD5 hashing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and work with it's output. (Always guaranteed to be the size of two `long` types.)

Comment: EDIT: also it seems using .getHashCode() % 100000 it also returns a number larger than 100.000 (says: index out of bounds), probably exausted the long type anyway. @EBrown I haven't tried yet, I'm not sure if it will dramaticly affect the running time though? Since the algorithm should work relatively fast.

Comment: @user2999349: you mention two values: *between 9'999* and *100000*. So I guess you only have 10'000 keys. `.GetHashCode()` is a method that is available in every object.

Comment: @user2999349 `GetHashCode()` **can** return negative numbers. You should use `Math.Abs(...)` to fix that.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if it's a typo or not, but `%100000` will map values between `0` and `99,999`. You indicated `0` and `9999`, which is incorrect. Which set do you need them between?

Comment: @EBrown Ah yes that's a typo, I meant 99,999 as well.

Comment: Is this homewoork? Anyway, the HashCode is something very common in .NET and it would be stupid to not use it to turn strings into a hashes even in an exercise (unless there are really special needs).

Comment: @StefanSteinegger Well yes it's an exercise and I have to write my own function for converting the string to a hash key, unfortunately...

Comment: @user2999349 The problem here, is that you have an **extremely high** potential for strings to generate the same "hash code" due to the way this algorithm works.

Comment: @EBrown How is that? I figured since the amount of possible characters for each position is 36, this way it'll build a unique number for each combination (which would be the reason for the possibly huge resulting numbers), as it's like a positional numeral system with base 36.

Comment: Until you use the `%100000` portion, which will return the same value for `1` and `100001`.

Answer (score 0):

To stick with your algorithm you don't need to calculate the whole number and do a mod at the end. You can change val to a `BigInteger` and mod as you go.

```
BigInteger val = 0;
long v;
long pow = name.Length-1;
foreach (char c in name) {
    if (char.IsNumber(c))
        v = (long)c;
    else
    {
        v = char.ToUpper(c) - 54; 
        val += v * (long)Math.Pow((double)36, (double)pow);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(v+","+pow+","+val);
    pow--;

    val = val % 100000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented something like this (because the HashCode is not usable outside of the machine).

I started with turning the string into a byte array:

```
        byte[] bytes = new byte[value.Length * sizeof(char)];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(value.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Then looping it and put it into an integer:

```
        foreach (var b in bytes)
        {
            hash ^= RotateLeft(b, position);
            position += 7;
        }
```

RotateLeft does bit shifting. These are details which may be different.